# Centos failing to upgrade bash

Tags: linux, centos, bash, update

I'm trying to resolve the recent Shellshock exploit however every time I run "yum update" or "yum update bash", it plainly says everything is up to date.

I'm pretty frustrated at the issue and probably missed a small thing which I have yet to find out...

I would extremely appreciate assistance, cheers!

Using CentOS 6.5 64-bit, just so you know!

An example of updating:

```
sudo yum update bash
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.hmc.edu
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: give us the output of `yum list bash`

Comment: Also, run this to check if you're vulnerable `env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test"`

Comment: `# yum list bash
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.hmc.edu
Installed Packages
bash.x86_64                                                                     4.1.2-15.el6_4                                                                     @anaconda-CentOS-201311291202.x86_64/6.5` and yes it is vulnerable

Comment: Did you disable the main CentOS repository? Because that's where you're going to get the update, not from EPEL.

Comment: Could be, I'm not that sure myself. I did fetch some more repositories like REMI and IUS just recently, but that didn't make a difference. But that's irrelevant :( How may I enable it again (I'm under the assumption it's disabled)?

Comment: Well, from your example output it shows that yum is only searching in EPEL. Remi and IUS aren't even listed. Figure out why it's not querying the CentOS repos and you'll figure it out. If you can't figure it out, you can always go fetch the rpm manually and install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had bad repositories!

Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`:

```
[base] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base 
baseurl=http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6 

[updates] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates 
baseurl=http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6 

[extras] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras 
baseurl=http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6 

[centosplus] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus 
baseurl=http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6 

[contrib] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib 
baseurl=http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
enabled=0 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

This fixed it for me, just type `yum clean all` after you're done editing the file, and `yum update` after that and it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad repositories"? What's bad about them? And I do not even have such a file CentOS-Base.repo...

Answer (score 4):

Do you have enabled the updates repository? Confirm with `yum repolist all` that the `updates` repository is available and enabled.

If you have the updates repository disabled you can enable the repository for a single yum command with:

```
yum  --enablerepo=updates update bash
```

or permanently by editing the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` configuration file.

Second, sometimes it helps if you clean the yum caches, with `yum clean all`

Comment: Tried the first command, didn't really do anything. Then I typed `yum clean all` and I believe that just created more errors, like some mirrors give me 404 errors. Additionally, updates is enabled as well. I'm still unsure.